# Weirdest issue : 2 cells with the same formula. One returns a spilled array, the other a #calc

Tags: excel

I am trying to figure out what the issue is.

I have a named array defined in the names manager, named "T" with a scope to the worksheet

In cell S2, the equation "=T" returns the calculated spilled array

In cell V2, the equation "=T" returns #CALC error

What may cause this?

I tried repairing the workbook. Excels finds no errors

I tried deleting the cache resulting in no effects

Forcing full recalculation CTRL+ALT+F9 has no effect

Referring to S2# in cell V2 returns the full spilled array

Forcing calculation as an array formula SHIFT+CTRL+ENTER has no effect

What steps should I take to clean the file?

UPDATE:
the name T is defined as `=INDEX(FILTER(Data85;(Data85[[Temps ]]>'Data 85C'!$H$32)*(Data85[[Temps ]]<'Data 85C'!K39));;1)` The reference `'Data 85C'!K39` keeps changing (revert to old state). It should be `'Data 85C'!H38` Changing the definition will make the cell V2 work, but will trigger the cell S2 to return a #CALC error instead.

I can't reproduce the issue in a new notebook

Comment: What is the actual definition of T?

Comment: =INDEX(FILTER(Data85;(Data85[[Temps ]]>'Data 85C'!$H$32)*(Data85[[Temps ]]<'Data 85C'!K39));;1)
The reference "'Data 85C'!K39" keeps changing. It should be "'Data 85C'!H38"
Changing the definition will make the cell V2 work, but will trigger S2 to return a #CALC error instead

Comment: Edit your question to show sample data, as well as the formula used to create the `Named array`. See [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Be sure to post your data as **Text** which can be easily copy/pasted, perhaps using this [Markdown Tables Generator](https://www.tablesgenerator.com/markdown_tables)

Comment: @RonRosenfeld I do not know how to reproduce the issue. Creating a new workbook with the same features does not trigger the issue. I suspect a corrupted workbook that needs to be cleansed, but starting from scratch is unthinkable.

Comment: Unfortunately, I will not be able to assist further with the information you have provided so far. Good luck!

Comment: The K39 reference is relative. Is it meant to be? If so, relative to what? If not, change it to $K$39

Comment: @Rory The relative reference is unintended, but it might have been the issue. The formula of the named array might updates depending on the selected cell. Let me check

Comment: @Rory Yep, that seemed to be the issue. Such a small mistake causing headache. I feel dumb now haha

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The question is dumber than it look.
The reference in the named array was relative to the selected cell when it was written.
Changing the selected cell triggers the reference to change, making any other named array referencing the first to be unable to calculate if the selected cell is changed between editions.

The solution is to make the reference absolute in the named array.